# Clarification of Direct sum meaning with $\geq 3$ subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Let $V$ be a vectorspace and $U_i$ subspaces of V. In the definition of $\oplus_{i \in I} U_i$ it is said that is does not suffice for $U_i$ to be pairwise disjoint. Instead we must have the stronger condition that $U_k \cup \displaystyle\sum_{i\in I, i\neq k} U_i=\{0_V\}$. By the summation is it meant that we are summing $U_i$ $i$ not $k$ but not direct summing?

Comment: Change your $\;\cup\;$ to $\;\cap\;$ and it will be correct. And the meaning is almost what you say, but the sum is "normal" over all subspaces $\;U_i\;,\;\;i\neq k\;$ . That **intersection** must be trivial (zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct statement is that $$U_k \cap \sum_{i \in I, \; I \neq k} U_i = \{0_V\}$$ for all $k$, where as you note the summation just means the set of things that can be written as finite linear sums of elements in the subspaces you're summing over.

The key point is that this allows you to show that anything in $\sum_{i \in I} U_i$ has a *unique* expression $u_1 + \ldots + u_n$ (where each $u_j$ is in $U_i$ for some $i$ that depends on $j$).